# Visual Studio 2005: \a escape sequence appears in string but can't remove

Tags: visual-studio-2005, escaping, j#

I'm working in J# with text extracted from MS Word using Excel interop. Right now I'm having a problem with text extracted from a cell. The cell is a row header, the visible text is "Total", but the extracted string is "Total\r\a". I want to remove the escape sequence, but VS won't detect or remove \a.

```
cellText = cellText.Replace("\r", ""); //works

cellText = cellText.Replace("\a", ""); //error: unrecognized escape sequence
cellText = cellText.Replace("\\a", ""); //doesn't remove the sequence
cellText.Contains("\\a") returns false.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the hex value of the last character?

Comment: 0x0007 . Is there a way to remove characters by hex code?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cellText = cellText.Replace("\a", ""); //error: unrecognized escape sequence
> ```

Well, `\a` is the standard escape sequence for C-like languages for the alert (bell) character, which usually makes a sound if sent to the console.  But Java doesn't support it (although most of the others are ok).  However, you can use a hex escape:

```
cellText = cellText.Replace("\u0007", "");
```

or an octal escape:

```
cellText = cellText.Replace("\007", "");
```

or if you're desperate to avoid the evil escape sequences:

```
char bell = 7;
cellText = cellText.Replace(bell.toString(), "");
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I ending up figuring this out:
    byte b = 0x0007;
    char c = (char)b;
    cellText = cellText.Replace(String.valueOf(c),"");

but I'll try the hex escape in your edit, as it would avoid creating new variables

Comment: cellText = cellText.Replace("\u0007", ""); does the trick. Nice and clean